# highcharts stockChart The function of the distance of movement of the graph with the mouse

Tags: highcharts, jstockchart

Tell me please. What function can be used to set the distance of the graph using the mouse?
https://prnt.sc/Mn_LdKTEwkp-
If I start moving the graph with the mouse to the left, the graph will move by 3 points.
https://prnt.sc/JZnmCkmWsSkt
It turns out when I move the graph with the mouse, with each movement the graph moves 3 points.

Question: How to set for example 10 points? So that every time the graph moves with the mouse, the graph moves through 10 points.

I do not know what to try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single option to configure the distance and it is related to the way how `oridinal` x-axis works in Highstock. [Here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/d5babd35b7d5f7dc0eca59d53c30304c044b056f/ts/Core/Axis/OrdinalAxis.ts#L623), in the source code, you can find out how it works exactly.

As a solution, you can disable the `ordinal` option or overwrite the `onChartPan` function.

```
xAxis: {
    ordinal: false
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hzfcm78n/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts